# Not exiting recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am writing a function which takes two lists, the second list is the same as the first, only it is shuffled and has one element removed. The function should return the missing element. I wrote this function

```
var findRemoved = function(firstArr, secondArr, indx){
    var indx = indx || 0;
    for(var i = 0; i<secondArr.length; i++){
        if(firstArr[indx] === secondArr[i]){
            findRemoved(firstArr, secondArr, ++indx);
        }
    }
    console.log("found end ", firstArr[indx]);
    return firstArr[indx];
```

}

When I run it with

```
var i = findRemoved([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [5,4,2,6,1,3]);
console.log("i ",i);
```

I get it console logging "found end ", 7, which is correct, however the recursion doesn't break at that point and keeps on going until it returns with the answer "2" Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: So what you want to do ? Do you want to get value which is not in second array ?

Comment: It looks like you're only trying to find ONE missing element because your return is for a single value.  Try adding an else statement to your recursive if and place the return statement in the else clause.  Therefore, if the element is found, the recursive function is executed, but if there is no match, the function returns the value.

Comment: @Michael because the second list is shuffled, if I were to do that, it would return the first element in the array, because the first element in the first array does not equal the first element in the second array

Comment: Why do you need recursion at all? It can be much simpler.

Comment: Im just trying to do it with recursion, for fun, im trying to get a better understanding of recursion.

Comment: @JakeSchievink If it's for fun no problem, but note that in JavaScript function calls are expensive, so loops have better performance than recursions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code continues running when finds the result, so for every index keeps looping and returning that index. You can return the index that comes from the recursion, and stop looping when you have found an ocurrence of the first array in the second.

Note: I didnt try to write a good implementation, only fix yours.

```
var findRemoved = function(firstArr, secondArr, indx){
  var indx = indx || 0;
  var result = null;
  for(var i = 0; result==null && i<secondArr.length; i++){
      if(firstArr[indx] === secondArr[i]){
          result = findRemoved(firstArr, secondArr, ++indx);
      }
  }
  result = result || firstArr[indx]
  console.log("found end ", result);
  return result;
}

var i = findRemoved([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [5,4,2,6,1,3]);
console.log("i ",i);
```

A fiddle of this: http://jsfiddle.net/b5Aus/

Comment: Thank you, and specifically, thank you for telling me what was wrong with mine and not just posting a code which fixes the problem but doesnt give me a solution.

Comment: For clarification, the return statement in my original code doesnt not stop the execution because there are other instances of findRemoved() which have already been initiated?

Comment: The console.log and the return is outside the loop. So for every call it will print the current number, firstArr[indx]. Forget for a second what is inside the loop. If we call the method with index, 0, 1, 2, 3, ... it will print the element in the firstArr with index 0,1,2... So it was recursing but not doing anything special about finding the right element.

Comment: You could also replace "result = ..." by "return ".

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this?

```
var findRemoved = function(firstArr, secondArr){
    for(var i=0, l=firstArr.length; i<l; ++i)
        if(secondArr.indexOf(firstArr[i]) < 0)
            return firstArr[i];
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work because the second array is shuffled

Comment: @JakeSchievink Look closer, I edited my answer because I realized that.

Comment: Also, why did you do, `for(var i=0, l=firstArr.length; i<l; ++i)` instead of `for(var i=0; i<firstArr.length; ++i)`

Comment: @JakeSchievink Because the loop condition runs at each iteration, and `i<l` is a bit faster than `i<firstArr.length`. Only matters if the array is huge.